# Spring InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException in async method using repository

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, asynchronous

in a RestController:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/apks")
public class ApkController {
    @Inject
    DecompiledApkRepository decompiledApkRepository;

    @Autowired
    DecompileService decompileService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> createFromJson(@RequestBody Apk apk) {
        ....
        DecompiledApk decompiledApk = new DecompiledApk(apk, apkFile, apk.getMd5Hash());
        decompileService.decompile(decompiledApk, apk.getMd5Hash(), decompiledApkRepository);

    } catch (IOException |InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return new ResponseEntity<>(null, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

The DecompiledApk entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "decompiled_apks")
public class DecompiledApk {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @JsonIgnore
    private Long id;

    @MapsId
    @OneToOne(optional=false)
    private Apk apk;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private URI decompiledFolder;

    @Transient
    @JsonIgnore
    private File inputApk;

 // all public getters/setters, package empty constructor and public full constructor
```

The DecompiledApkRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface DecompiledApkRepository extends CrudRepository<DecompiledApk, Long> {
    DecompiledApk findByApk_md5Hash(String md5Hash);
}
```

And here, the problem is in the async method in the DecompileService:

```
@Service
public class DecompileService {
    private static final String DEC_FOLDER = "/tmp/decompiled/";


    @Async
    public Future<Void> decompile(DecompiledApk decompiledApk, String md5Hash, DecompiledApkRepository decompiledApkRepository) throws InterruptedException {
        /*
       ...
       */
        decompiledApk.setDecompiledFolder(URI.create(outputFolder));
        System.err.println("---start-->"+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        decompiledApkRepository.save(decompiledApk);
        System.err.println("---end-->"+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        return new AsyncResult<>(null);
    }
```

The instruction:

```
decompiledApkRepository.save(decompiledApk);
```

throw:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist: com.xxx.domain.Apk; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.xxx.domain.Apk
```

But if I remove the @Async annotation it works without problem!
Any ideas?
Do you need more details?

Answer (score 0):

Although the method has been marked as asynchronous, there are no spring transaction markers , suspect that is causing is the problem.
Try adding Spring transaction :

```
org.springframework.transaction.annotation  


@Transactional
```

Hopefully that will solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

> Spring's transaction context is preserved using `ThreadLocals`. This means that your SessionFactory is only available to the thread dispatching your request thus, if you create a new thread, you will get a null and a corresponding exception.
>   What your `@Async` method does is use a `TaskExecutor` to run your method in another thread. So the problem described above is happening with your service.

According to [link](http://haomengapp.com/questions/2579136/spring-async-null-hibernate-session-on-lazy-collection)

Comment: But if I breakp the instruction 
`decompiledApkRepository.save(decompiledApk);` both `apk` and `decompiledApkRepository` variables aren't null... and seems that I can use their methods...